# Variable inside jquery not accessible outsite

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following code to get data from a php file to a variable 'line'. But I don't know why, when I alert its value outside, it show empty. Here is the code:

```
var line = "something"
function generateNewLine(line)
      {
        $.get("getLine.php", function( data ) {
          line = data
          alert(line) // prints the data
        });

        alert(line) // prints nothing
      }
```

Comment: Can you give more details, like how and where do you invoke generateNewLine?

Comment: you have 2 main problems ... the first i linked to and the other is very basic javascript scope.

Comment: remove your second var